# How not to get a repeated attribute of an object?

Tags: python, for-loop, object, oop, set

I want to make a kind of "register system" but in a bank using objects, so you as customer have to create your account, therefore, you can´t have same name (username) of other customer.

I tried this:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, name, pin, balance):
        self.name = name
        self.pin = pin
        self.balance = balance

    def __get_name__(self):
        return self.name

    def __set_name__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get_pin__(self):
        return self.pin

    def __set_pin__(self, pin):
        self.pin = pin

    def __get_balance__(self):
        return self.balance

    def __set_balance__(self, balance):
        self.balance = balance

    def _deposit(self, deposition_amount):
        self.balance += deposition_amount

    def _withdraw(self, withdrawal_amount):
        self.balance -= withdrawal_amount

set_of_accounts = set()

def create_account():
    name = input("Input name : ")
    for account in set_of_accounts:
        if account.__get_name__() == name:
            print('There is other account with same name, try a new one')
        else:
                pin = str(input("Please input a pin of your choice : "))
                balance = eval(input("Please input a amount to deposit to start an account : "))

                account = Account(name, pin, balance)
                set_of_accounts.add(account)

                print("\n----New account created successfully !----")
                print("Note! Please remember the Name and Pin")
                print("========================================")

def print_all_customers():
    print("Customer name list and balances mentioned below : \n")

    if len(set_of_accounts) > 0:
        for account in set_of_accounts:
            print("->. Customer = " + str(account.__get_name__()))
            print("->. Balance = " + str(account.__get_balance__()) + " -/Rs\n")
    else:
        print("No accounts are persisted yet.\n")
    input("Please press enter key to go back to main menu to perform another function or exit ...")

def menu():
    while True:
        print("*************************************")
        print("=<< 1. Open a new account         >>=")
        print("=<< 2. Withdraw Money             >>=")
        print("=<< 3. Deposit Money              >>=")
        print("=<< 4. Check Customers & Balance  >>=")
        print("=<< 5. Exit/Quit                  >>=")
        print("*************************************")
        choiceNumber = input("Select your choice number from the above menu : ")
        if choiceNumber == "1":
            create_account()
        elif choiceNumber == "2":
            pass
        elif choiceNumber == "3":
            pass
        elif choiceNumber == "4":
            print_all_customers()
        elif choiceNumber == "5":
            exit()
        else:
            print("Invalid option")

menu()
```

My problem is in `create_account()` because after I wrote the name the program doesn´t get inside of the for loop. So I'm lost because I don't know why the for loop is not executed.
I hope someone can help me, and I accept sugestions if you have other idea for do it.

Comment: If set of accounts is empty. How do you think for loop will execute? You need to add a special condition to checkl if the set if empty.

Comment: You don't need a separate for loop:  `if any(acc.__get_name__() == name) for acc in set_of_accounts):`

Comment: What's up with the dunder methods? `__names_like_this__` are reserved for the Python core language and standard library. `__set_name__` in particular is [already used](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set_name__) for a descriptor feature.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the loop inside the `create_account` method, which is also compounded by the use of dunder methods. Before we fix the create_account method I would propose to refactor the Account class so that the class is clearer. Then move on to create a class to handling checking if the Account has been created. Then fix the create account method.

**Dunder Methods**

Dunder methods or double underscore methods are special or magic methods that are never intended to be called directly. An Example of this is the `__init__` method.

If we were to create a new account object we do not call `__init__` directly, instead we call `Account()` then python will behind the scenes call `__init__` this keeps the code cleaner as we don't have **init** function call strewn though out the code, rather we see `Account()` which is much clearer. Python does this for many things for example `==` calls the dunder method `__eq__`.

Because __ on methods will confuse people and can introduce unwanted side effects into your program, We should clean out all the __ from your methods.

Another convention is single underscore, this is used to that the variables are private. Because you call the _deposit and _withdraw methods from outside the Account class it is conversion to shift the single underscore onto some "private variables". The main reason you would do this is for type hints, so let's type-hint the whole class.

With these changes the account class would look like this:

```
class Account:

    _name: str
    _pin: str
    _balance: int

    def __init__(self, name: str, pin: str, balance: int):
        self._name = name
        self._pin = pin
        self._balance = balance

    def get_name(self) -> str:
        return self._name

    def set_name(self, _name):
        self._name = _name

    def get_pin(self) -> str:
        return self._pin

    def set_pin(self, _pin: str):
        self._pin = _pin

    def get_balance(self) -> int:
        return self._balance

    def set_balance(self, balance: int):
        self._balance = balance

    def deposit(self, deposition_amount: int):
        self._balance += deposition_amount

    def withdraw(self, withdrawal_amount: int):
        self._balance -= withdrawal_amount
```

**Account Checker**

Changing the way the accounts stored will make it much easier to check whether an account exists or not. To do this let's create a Bank class that will keep track of all account in the program.

```
 class Bank:

    accounts: dict

    def __init__(self):
        self.accounts = dict()

    def __contains__(self, account: Account) -> bool:
        return account.get_name() in self.accounts.keys()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.accounts.values().__iter__()

    def empty(self) -> bool:
        return len(self.accounts) < 1

    def name_taken(self, name: str) -> bool:
        return name in self.accounts.keys()

    def create_account(self, name: str, pin: str, balance: int):
        self.accounts[name] = Account(name, pin, balance)
```

As you can see the Bank class stores all the accounts in a dictionary. Is dictionary is much like a list but rather accessing the objects in a list by an integer, a dictionary access objects by another object (key).

[image]

The dunder method `__init__` is a normal conductor which just sets up a dictionary to hold all the accounts in the program.

The dunder method `__iter__` allows us to use bank in for loops e.g. `for account in bank:`. When we iterate through the bank object we want to go through all the values stored in the dictionary.

The empty methods check to see if the dictionary has any items.

The name_taken checks to see if any keys matching the name passed in. If they do match we know that name has been taken and we cannot use that.

The create account allows us to just pass in components of an Account and have it created correctly as well as placed correctly in the dictionary.

**Fixing Create Account**

With these two changes made fixing the create_account will be much easier.

First let's look at the code which is going wrong:

```
def create_account():
    name = input("Input name : ")
    for account in set_of_accounts:
        if account.__get_name__() == name:
            print('There is other account with same name, try a new one')
        else:
                pin = str(input("Please input a pin of your choice : "))
                balance = eval(input("Please input a amount to deposit to start an account : "))

                account = Account(name, pin, balance)
                set_of_accounts.add(account)

                print("\n----New account created successfully !----")
                print("Note! Please remember the Name and Pin")
                print("========================================")
```

Imagine we type in 'Sam' as input and have zero Accounts in set_of_accounts. name will be set to 'Sam', but then because set_of_accounts is empty nothing in the for loop will be run.

Imagine again we type in 'Sam' as input inputs and have many Accounts in set_of_accounts. Then we would try to create a new account every time 'Sam' did not an account whose name is not 'Sam'.

Another thing we should be careful of is editing a collection while iterating through the same collection. editing the set_of_accounts by  `set_of_accounts.add(account)` inside `for account in set_of_accounts:` could give us incorrect behavior.

Thinking about the program in this way shows us that rather than having a check inside a loop, we want to do a single check and create an Account if it does not exist or ask for another name if it is already taken.

This these changes create_account would look like this:

```
def create_account():
    name = input("Input name : ")

    # keep asking for a new name if the name still exists
    while bank.name_taken(name):
        name = input('There is other account with same name, try a new one:')

    pin = str(input("Please input a pin of your choice : "))
    balance = read_integer("Please input a amount to deposit to start an account : ")

    bank.create_account(name, pin, balance)

    print("\n----New account created successfully !----")
    print("Note! Please remember the Name and Pin")
    print("========================================")
```

As we can see `create_account` now does one check per name. and once the name is unique it will go on read in the pin and a balance, and then create a new account through the `create_account` method.

[A fully working version of your refactored code can be found here.](https://www.online-python.com/RM0f6cGv2E)

Message me if you have any questions.

Comment: In `print_all_customers()` you iterate in `bank` object to print all accounts or that is what I understand, but I would like to know why it is not possible to iterate directly the `self.accounts` dictionary to print all accounts? @user1239299

Comment: `self.accounts.__iter__()` would give us an iterator that would return a (<Name>, <Account>) pair. When we want to list all the accounts we only care about Account objects so it makes sense to iterate through the values of the dictionary which contain only accounts.  But what is an iterator? An iterator is a object which tracks the current item in a for loop; whether a for loop can keep looping etc. Dictionarys, Lists and other collections don't have the neccary data / methods for looping in them. The `__iter__` is called when we want to loop so we must return an iterator not a collection

Answer (score 0):

Just u have to make a little tweak in your code where you should create one more `set object` name `name` which act like a `register of name` in bank. So update `create_account` function code to last code.

**UPDATE :**

```
set_of_accounts = set()

def create_account():
    name = input("Input name : ")
    for account in set_of_accounts:
        if account.__get_name__() == name:
            print('There is other account with same name, try a new one')
        else:
                pin = str(input("Please input a pin of your choice : "))
                balance = eval(input("Please input a amount to deposit to start an account : "))

                account = Account(name, pin, balance)
                set_of_accounts.add(account)

                print("\n----New account created successfully !----")
                print("Note! Please remember the Name and Pin")
                print("========================================")
```

**TO :**

```
set_of_accounts = set()
names = set()
def create_account():
    name = input("Input name : ")
    if name in names:
            print('There is other account with same name, try a new one')
    else:
                pin = str(input("Please input a pin of your choice : "))
                balance = eval(input("Please input a amount to deposit to start an account : "))

                account = Account(name, pin, balance)
                set_of_accounts.add(account)
                names.add(name)
                print("\n----New account created successfully !----")
                print("Note! Please remember the Name and Pin")
                print("========================================")
```